# php - рекурсивний поиск по массиву с поиском regex ключа

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения, search

Имеется массив:

```
[my:МоиПоля] => Array
    (
        [attr] => Array
            (
                [xmlns:xsi] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
                [xmlns:pc] => http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls
                [xmlns:ma] => http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/metadata/properties/metaAttributes
                [xmlns:d] => http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields
                [xmlns:q] => http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/queryFields
                [xmlns:dfs] => http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution
                [xmlns:dms] => http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types
                [xmlns:my] => http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2016-04-22T08:03:54
                [xmlns:xd] => http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003
                [xml:lang] => uk-UA
            )

        [my:ODM_Total] => Array
            (
                [my:Date] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 2017-05-09
                    )

                [my:TotalScore] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 384
                    )

                [my:Description] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [my:Manager] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => "I"
                    )

                [my:Store] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 3101
                    )

            )

        [my:Clean] => Array
            (
                [my:Total_Clean] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 63
                    )

                [my:CH_1] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => true
                    )

                [my:L_1] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 5
                    )

                [my:CH_2] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => true
                    )

                [my:L_2] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 5
                    )

                [my:CH_3] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => true
                    )

                [my:CH_4] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => true
                    )

                [my:L_4] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 5
                    )

                [my:L_3] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 5
                    )

                [my:CH_5] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => false
                    )

                [my:L_5] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [my:CH_6] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => true
                    )

                [my:L_6] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 5
                    )
```

И т.д.

Нужно сделать функцию для поиска за ключом в виде `"/my:CH_\d+/"` и чтобы в результате получился массив:

```
array(
    [my:CH_1]=>array(
            [value]=>true
        )  ...
```

На данный момент есть только вот такая функция:

```
function searchExc($array, $key)
{

    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key2=>$subarray) {
          if (preg_match($key,$key2))
            if(is_array($array[$key2]) && isset($array[$key2]['value'])) {
                $results[] = $array;
          }

            $results = array_merge($results, searchExc($subarray, $key, $value));
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

но она не выводит то что надо...
Она выводит это:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [my:Total_Clean] => Array
            (
                [value] => 63
            )

        [my:CH_1] => Array
            (
                [value] => true
            )

        [my:L_1] => Array
            (
                [value] => 5
            )

        [my:CH_2] => Array
            (
                [value] => true
            )

        [my:L_2] => Array
            (
                [value] => 5
            )

        [my:CH_3] => Array
            (
                [value] => true
            )

        [my:CH_4] => Array
            (
                [value] => true
            )

        [my:L_4] => Array
            (
                [value] => 5
            )

        [my:L_3] => Array
            (
                [value] => 5
            )
```

что-то не так с функцией, поэтому прошу помочь.
Искал по всем ресурсам и не могу найти...
Наперед спасибо за ответы.

Дополнительно:

Массив многомерный и эти ключи могут быть разбросаны в разных измерениях
и нужно найти все ключи с данным схождением.

Comment: @Visman, Спасибо за правку, не очень силен в русском...

Comment: В итоге должен получиться массив, где все ключи `CH_` будут на первом уровне?

Comment: @rjhdby, все верно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$input=['k1'=>['my:CH_1'=>['a'=>'b'],'c'=>'b'],'k2'=>'v2','my:CH_2'=>'k2'];
$output = [];

function walk($input, &$output){
    foreach($input as $key => $value){
        if(substr($key, 0, 6) === 'my:CH_') $output[$key] = $value;
        if(is_array($value)) walk($value, $output);
    }
}
walk($input, $output);

var_dump($output);
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e12587a2d7ac5030be8ad7c5ff4afea75b973a67)

Comment: не работает, вернулся пустой масив...

Comment: сори... мой косяк...

Comment: забыл проверить данные на вхождение